# Query Params - API Rest

Tags: node.js, api, parameters

Is it possible to include more than one parameter in a API?

Ex.:
GET
url/Proposal/Consult?**strSituation=17**

I need to get **strSituation 17, 18 and 05**.

Comment: It depends entirely on the API.  Are you writing the API itself, or are you writing the consuming front-end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an API implementer you have a couple of options here:

- you can make a request like `?strSituation=17,18,05` and ensure that your backend handles comma-separated values
- or you can repeat the parameter, as in `?strSituation=17&strSituation=18&strSituation=05`

If this is not your API, then you'll need to consult the docs to learn how this particular API handles it.